# Convert date string to unix timestamp

Tags: php

I have a string:

`Mon Jul 07 2014 13:47:03 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`

I want to convert to unix timestamp in PHP.

However using `strtotime()` does not work for me. Is there any other work around so I can get the unix timestamp from this string?

Comment: is that the exact string? `Mon Jul .... Standard Time)`? strtotime() is good, but you can't just throw anything you want it. you should strip off the "(Malay Penninsula Standard Time)" at least.

Comment: Yes that is the exact string, i am trying to convert the lastdatemodified from a javascript function when it throws over the value to my php end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, strip `(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)` because you have one more time the timezone on `GMT+0800`, you can clean your datetime string with substr like

```
$dateString = "Mon Jul 07 2014 13:47:03 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";
$dateString = substr($dateString, 0, strpos($dateString, '('));
```

after remove this you can use DateTime Object like

```
$date = new DateTime($dateString); //Mon Jul 07 2014 13:47:03 GMT+0800

echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Which function should i use to identify the column to strip?

Comment: @user3148070 You could always use string_replace